# Issue with nav sub menu not reappearing

Tags: jquery, css

I have an issue with a sub-menu on a navigation bar not displaying after jQuery sets the css.   When I click on a sub-menu item, the container gets set to `display:none` but when I hover over the menu item again, the sub-menu does not display.

```css
.navmenu {
     height: 32px;
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: justify;
}
 .navmenu li {
     display: inline-block;
     line-height: 2em;
}
 .navmenu li a {
     display: block;
     font-family: THCFontSemiBold;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #f3ac3f;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .navmenu li:hover {
     background: #6d1238;
}
 .navmenu li ul {
     margin: 13px 0px 0px 7px;
     padding: 0;
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     background: #510E2A;
     border: 2px solid #AA6180;
     list-style-type: none;
     box-shadow: 5px 10px 15px #000;
     z-index: 1;
     visibility: hidden;
}
 .navmenu li ul:before, .navmenu ul:after {
     content: '';
     height: 0px;
     width: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -15px;
     left: 10px;
}
 .navmenu li ul:before {
     border-left: 15px solid transparent;
     border-right: 15px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 15px solid #AA6180;
}
 .navmenu li ul:after {
     border-left: 15px solid transparent;
     border-right: 15px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 15px solid #510E2A;
     top: -12px;
}
 .navmenu li ul li {
     line-height: 1.8em;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
     margin: 8px;
}
 .navmenu li:hover ul {
     visibility: visible;
}
 .navmenu:after {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
     clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navd">
   <ul class="navmenu">
      <li><a href="#" id="mnu_Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="mnu_aboutus">About Us</a></li>
      <li>
         <a href="#" id="mnu_services">Services</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="mnu_painmanagement">Pain Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="mnu_weightloss">Weight Loss</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="mnu_cosmetic">Cosmetic Procedure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="mnu_vitamins">Vitamin Injections</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="mnu_testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="mnu_patientforms">Patient Forms</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="mnu_contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="mnu_patientportal">Patient Portal</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Please advise on how I can correct this or any other suggestions on how to handle this menu on both a desktop and a mobile device (mobile device does not hide the sub menu when you hover out of the container).

[My Fiddle is Here](https://jsfiddle.net/p8ho951w/51/)

Comment: What is the purpose of the click function? Once you click it, you hide it, then what happens?

Comment: The problem is that `toggle` adds an inline style attribute to the item. Inline styles overrule external stylesheet styles.

Comment: @LinkinTed click function used mostly for mobile device.  Once I hide the sub menu, I cannot get it to display again if I hover over the main menu item.

Comment: @LinkinTed I tried to hide the submenu by setting the `.css("display","none")` but I get the same results.

Comment: Use bootstrap or copy the behaviour (classes and js) that affect this job:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

As commented, the `toggle()` function adds a inline `style="display:none"` to the element.

You can fix by adding an lightly timed out function to remove the attribute.

```js
$("#mnu_services_drop a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#mnu_services_drop").toggle();
}).on('mouseup', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#mnu_services_drop").removeAttr('style');
   }, 100);
});
```

```css
.navmenu {
  background: #510E2A;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: justify;
}

.navmenu li {
  float: left;
}

.navmenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: THCFontSemiBold;
  color: #f3ac3f;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navmenu li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;
  top: -1px;
  left: 35px;
  display: none;
}

.navmenu li ul li {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.navmenu li ul a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.navmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">Main 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Main 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Main 3</a>
    <ul id="mnu_services_drop">
      <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Main 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Main 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Main 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Main 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Seems to work well on a desktop but no properly on a tablet.  The sub-menu will not hide on the tablet.

Comment: Retooled my code as an edit and now I don't see it here.  I need to find a solution to this issue.